# jQuery .height() function keeps adding height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically setting height of iframe, i.e `middle_frame`, but first, when I set it to some value, next time it is added up. Value is not reset. What should I do ?

```
        var a=$('#middle_frame').height();
        var b=$('#regis_selectionpanel').height();
        var h=a+b+550;
        alert('a='+a+',b='+b+',Register height is '+h);
        //$('#middle').height('0px');

        $('#middle').height(h+'px');
```

I tried first setting it to 0, but it's still not working.

Comment: What are you seeing in the alert? and what are you expecting? What do you mean by "next time it is added up" and "not reset"? Please explain exactly what you are doing and what is happening compared to what you expect.

Comment: @smerny On 2 differnt Events i want to get iframe size and then set parent Div size , what happends is first if i get h=100 and i set to 0 , next time when i click again h=100 and when i set height,it  become 200

Comment: Is there any chance that `#middle` is a child of either element, or that its dimension does affect the computed height of either?

Always try to replicate your problem with a fiddle - easier for us all to troubleshoot.